# Matrix of pairwise column sums

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, reference-request

In a problem I want to solve, the following construction pops up:

Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices over any ring (or even additive monoid, if you want) with the same number $d$ of rows. We define $A \ast B$ to be the matrix of all pairwise sums of columns of $A$ and $B$. That is, a column of $A \ast B$ is a sum of a column of $A$ with a column of $B$ and you take all of these sums. (At the end, you can delete all columns that appear more than once, if you want.)

Does this construction have a name? Does it appear somewhere in mathmatics and was studied there? For instance, are there combinatorial considerations of this when all entries of $A$ and $B$ are non-negative integers?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This $A * B$ matrix with $d$ lines and $pq$ columns where $p$, resp. $q$, is the number of columns of $A$, resp. $B$ with deletion of columns that appear more than once looks like the construction of the **Minkowski sum** of two polytopes in $\mathbb{R^d}$ with $p+1$ (resp. $q+1$) vertices, one of their vertices being the origin, the coordinates of the others being the columns of $A$, resp. $B$.

But a restriction is that this notion is made for **convex sets**.
The Minkowski sum "ignores" points that are inside the convex hull of what you call $A*B$.

See for example the wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) or the PhD thesis [there](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/109334?ln=en).

I can give further details.

Comment: See as well [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Minkowski_sum_2/).

Comment: Interesting references. (+1)